# GraphQL Apollo schema delegation: info.mergeInfo is undefined

Tags: graphql, apollo

I followed the official [doc to delegate a graphql schema](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-delegation) which indicates that in order to do so, one must use the method `delegateSchema` that can be found on the property `mergeInfo` of the argument `info` passed down to resolvers:

```
resolver: (parent, args, ctx, info) => {
  return info.mergeInfo.delegateSchema({
    // Schema delegation options...
  })
}
```

But there is no property `mergeInfo` on the `info` argument ! And so I get this error message: `GraphQL Error GraphQL error: Cannot read property 'delegateToSchema' of undefined` which is normal considering these are the top-level properties of `info`:

```
console.log(Object.keys(info))
```

```
[
  'fieldName',
  'fieldNodes',
  'returnType',
  'parentType',
  'path',
  'schema',
  'fragments',
  'rootValue',
  'operation',
  'variableValues',
  'cacheControl'
]
```

It even looks like that `mergeInfo` is not mentioned in the [type definition of the `GraphQLResolveInfo` object](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/c82ff68f52722c20f10da69c9e50a030a1f218ae/src/type/definition.js#L489-L500)

Is the doc outdated or am I missing something ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mergeInfo` is only injected into the info object when you use `mergeSchemas` to stitch together two or more schemas. Additionally, it will *only* be injected into the resolvers for fields you add as part of the schema stitching -- resolvers for the schemas will not be impacted (it doesn't really make sense to *delegate* to another schema in the context of one of the existing schemas anyway).

Here's a simple example:

```
const { makeExecutableSchema, mergeSchemas } = require('graphql-tools')

const schemaA = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: `
    type Query {
      foo: String
    }
  `,
})
const schemaB = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: `
    type Query {
      bar: String
    }
  `,
})
const typeDefs = `
  extend type Query {
    foobar: String
  }
`
const schema = mergeSchemas({
  schemas: [schemaA, schemaB, typeDefs],
})
```

Here, the resolvers for `foo` and `bar` will not have access to `mergeInfo`, but the resolver for `foobar` will.

Comment: Looks like v6 of graphql-tools does not take typeDefs in the schemas array, but instead accepts it in a new `typeDefs` key.  Have you seen this and do you know how it interacts with mergeInfo?